# How do I find out what a linux command does exactly?

Tags: linux, command-line

When I run something like `python file.py`, the system is (I think) executing some file with `file.py` as an argument. How do I find out exactly which file it is executing or at least the directory?

Is there a Linux command that let's you find the targets of other commands?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"What a command does" is not well defined and is an ambiguous sentence. All of them have [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29) (at the very least, burning CPU cycles is heating your processor).

<sup>I am assuming your command is not malicious or hostile, and your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) is some Linux...</sup>

Very often, **a command has *some* documentation**. So for command *`foo`* try `apropos`*`foo`* and `man`*`foo`* and often *`foo`*`--help` (required by GNU [coding standard](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Command_002dLine-Interfaces.html)) or else STFW. If the command is packaged in your distribution, it might have a separate documentation package (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is packaged as `gcc-5`, `g++-5`, `gccgo-5` etc... on my Debian/Sid, but there is also a `gcc-5-doc` package etc... I recommend installing most documentation packages of the software you are using... and also `manpages` & `manpages-dev` &  `manpages-posix` & `manpages-posix-dev` on Debian related distributions).

Every [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) is doing some [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (which is the most common way to do observable side effects, such as input & output). The possible Linux syscalls are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). You can **find the sequence of the *dynamically* executed syscalls of a command** or process **with  [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)** (some few "syscalls" like [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) are often not true system calls done by the kernel, see [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) for details).

Try for a simple example:

```
 strace pwd
```

and you'll see that it is doing about 70 system calls, notably on my Debian/PC:

```
getcwd("/home/basile", 4096)            = 13
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)
                                        = 0x7f61aac5a000
write(1, "/home/basile\n", 13)          = 13
```

See also [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html), which traces calls to functions inside shared libraries.

At last, **most Linux commands are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software)**, so you can download and ***study* their [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code)**, and even improve it.

As others answered, **your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29) is searching an [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)** (which you could query with `echo $PATH`), and you could use `which`*`foo`*  and `whereis`*`foo`* and `type`*`foo`*  to find more about *`foo`*. Of course, shells have some *builtin* commands, such as `cd` (which makes the shell *itself* do a [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall, so there cannot be any [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable for the `cd` command, which has to be a builtin), and most shells enable you to define shell [functions](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) and [aliases](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

<sup>PS. Even for understanding malicious commands, `strace` can be very useful.</sup>

Comment: ltrace will track library calls

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a Linux command that let's you find the targets of other commands?

Yes, it's called **which** in my machine when I run:

```
$ which python
$ /usr/bin/python
```

Normally in linux, unless you specify the current directory by the following:

```
./any_command
```

The bash (or the shell you are using) will look into the directories listed in your PATH environment variable trying to find a command with the given name.

The PATH is a list of directories separated by ":" character. Normally it has already some default locations where your shell will look for executables like /bin, /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin (the root user has different paths in his $PATH env variable).

If you have some location which you would like to add to your path you can do this by running the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/my_new_location
```

This way you can start running programs located in the my_new_location directory from anywhere without specifying the whole path to them. The order is important, if the same command appears in two different directories the command from the first directory in the list is used. Thus, if you would like to give precedence to your my_new_location you have to put it in the front of the PATH variable as in the following declaration:

```
export PATH=/my_new_location:$PATH
```